# Different behaviour when wrapping code in extension function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm starting my main activity from a callback, this works fine:

```
private val callback: BarcodeCallback = object : BarcodeCallback {
    override fun barcodeResult(result: BarcodeResult) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)  
    }
}
```

I found a [generic extension method](https://gist.github.com/passsy/3e6a12150af02120f8c6c156100277cc) for launching activities:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Context.launchActivity(
        options: Bundle? = null,
        noinline init: Intent.() -> Unit = {}) {

    val intent = newIntent<T>(this)
    intent.init()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        startActivity(intent, options)
    } else {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> newIntent(context: Context): Intent =
        Intent(context, T::class.java)
```

When I use this method instead (`applicationContext.launchActivity<MainActivity>()`) I get an exception: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag`

Why is the behaviour different? I'm not setting the flag in my original attempt, which works fine.

Comment: In the first snippet, `startActivity()` is being called on the current `Activity` (presumably), so you don't need that flag. In the extension, it's being called on whatever the receiver is, which is `applicationContext` when you do `applicationContext.launchActivity<>()`, so you need that flag.

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm right. So is there any way to make the extension aware of the calling context, without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could check if the receiver `Context` is not an `Activity` descendant – e.g., `if (this !is Activity)`, or similar – and add the flag if so. You could avoid having to do that, however, by calling `launchActivity()` on the current `Activity`, instead of `applicationContext` (though I'm not sure where or how else you intend to use that extension).

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, I guess the problem is that I don't know how to access the activity from withing the callback

Comment: @MikeM. Think I found out how. `this@ScannerActivity.launchActivity<MainActivity> {  }`. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Bingo. You got it.

Comment: @MikeM. Alright, thanks for your time. Could you add an answer for some well deserved internet points?

Comment: No problem. I don't have time to put together a proper answer right now, but I'll try to get to it later, when I get a chance, if no one else has gotten to it first. If I forget, please feel free to post one yourself, so you can close out your question. Thank you, and cheers!